# Rails. Gem bundle failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundler

after I run:

> bundle install

I got:

> /usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:14:in `<top
>   (required)>': undefined method`remove' for Gem::QuickLoader:Module
>   (NoMethodError)   from :158:in `require'    from
>   <internal:gem_prelude>:158:in`load_full_rubygems_library'    from
>   :280:in `method_missing'    from
>   /usr/local/bin/bundle:19:in`'
>   mat@Macbook-Pro~/Documents/workspace/RoR/rails_projects/sample_app$

Edited:

```
>bundle -v 
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:14:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `remove' for Gem::QuickLoader:Module (NoMethodError)
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:158:in `require'
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:158:in `load_full_rubygems_library'
    from <internal:gem_prelude>:280:in `method_missing'
    from /usr/local/bin/bundle:19:in `<main>'

mat@Macbook-Pro~$ gem -v
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:86:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `load_plugins' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)
    from /usr/local/bin/gem:9:in `require'
    from /usr/local/bin/gem:9:in `<main>'
```

My Gemfile is :

>

```
 source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.9'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.3'

group :development do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'
end

group :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'
  gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
end

# Use unicorn as the web server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Deploy with Capistrano
# gem 'capistrano'

# To use debugger (ruby-debug for Ruby 1.8.7+, ruby-debug19 for Ruby 1.9.2+)
# gem 'ruby-debug'
# gem 'ruby-debug19', :require => 'ruby-debug'

# Bundle the extra gems:
# gem 'bj'
# gem 'nokogiri'
# gem 'sqlite3-ruby', :require => 'sqlite3'
# gem 'aws-s3', :require => 'aws/s3'

# Bundle gems for the local environment. Make sure to
# put test-only gems in this group so their generators
# and rake tasks are available in development mode:
# group :development, :test do
#   gem 'webrat'
# end
```

Could anybody help me?THanks!

Comment: What version of bundle and rubygems are you running? `bundle -v` and `gem -v`. Have you tried updating one or the other?

Comment: @Casper please see updated info. bundle -v and gem -v generate eror messages.

Comment: Ok..so when did these problems start? What did you change recently that broke it? Or is this the first time you are using ruby?

Comment: @Casper Today. I cannot what I did abnormal. not using RoR today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to manually update to the latest RubyGems version from here:

http://rubygems.org/pages/download

```
1. Download the latest rubygems 
   http://production.cf.rubygems.org/rubygems/rubygems-1.8.7.tgz
2. Extract it 
   tar zxvf rubygems-1.8.7.tgz
3. Install it
   cd rubygems-1.8.7
   sudo ruby setup.rb
```

If that does not help you can try and download an older version of rubygems from here:
http://rubyforge.org/frs/?group_id=126

For example 1.8.5, 1.8.0, 1.7.0, 1.6.0.

Comment: I also got this:$ sudo gem update --system 1.8.5
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/gem_runner.rb:86:in `<top (required)>': undefined method `load_plugins' for Gem:Module (NoMethodError)
 from /usr/local/bin/gem:9:in `require'
 from /usr/local/bin/gem:9:in `<main>'

Comment: You can't use `gem update --system` because your whole RubyGems module is broken (the gem command comes from RubyGems, and it's broken for you). That is why you need to follow my instructions instead, and install "by hand".

Comment: If everything else fails I suggest you remove all ruby packages from your system and reinstall ruby from scratch. But I'm pretty sure if you just install the right RubyGems version you'll get it working too. You simply seem to have some sort of incompatibility issue with Ruby/RubyGems right now.

Answer (score 2):

I faced with a similar error:

```
$ bundle -v

/Users/Reza/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems.rb:14:in `<top         (required)>': undefined method `remove' for Gem::QuickLoader:Module (NoMethodError)
```

It seems that all **[..]/rubygems.rb Undefined method[..]** issues is related to a conflict between installed rubygems (e.g. via rvm rubygems) and built in rubygems methods in ruby 1.9.x

just rename the installed rubygems files and issue is resolved.

```
$ which ruby
/Users/Reza/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-rc2/bin/ruby
$ echo $MY_RUBY_HOME
/Users/Reza/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-rc2
$ cd "$MY_RUBY_HOME/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/"
$ mv rubygems.rb rubygems.rb-rename
$ mv rubygems rubygems-rename
$ bundle -v
Bundler version 1.0.18
```